# Cannot run a Windows command via Ant, but can on cmd.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, ant, service

I have an ant macro I want to run;

```
<macrodef name="serviceTask">
    <attribute name="server"/>
    <attribute name="operation"/>
    <attribute name="service"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="sc \\@{server} @{operation} @{service}"/>
        <exec executable="sc.exe" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="\\@{server} @{operation} @{service}"/>
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="startTomcat">
    <echo message="Start Tomcat ${service} on ${server}"/>
    <serviceTask server="MyServer" operation="start" service="Tomcat8180"/>
</target>
```

But I get an RPC error:

```
startTomcat:
     [echo] Start Tomcat Tomcat8180 on pacdcdtadeva02
     [echo] sc \\pacdcdtadeva02 start Tomcat8180
     [exec] [SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 1722:
     [exec]
     [exec] The RPC server is unavailable.
     [exec]

stopTomcat:
     [echo] Stop Tomcat Service Tomcat8180 on pacdcdtadeva02
     [echo] sc \\pacdcdtadeva02 stop Tomcat8180
     [exec] [SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 1722:
     [exec]
     [exec] The RPC server is unavailable.
     [exec]
     [echo] -------------------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] --- Completed on 02/01/2011 05:11:42 PM
     [echo] -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now when I run this from the command line like

```
sc \\stage01 start Tomcat8180
```

the service starts/stops

```
C:\usr\svn_workspaces\xIVR\agent-ivr>sc \\stage01 start Tomcat8180

SERVICE_NAME: Tomcat8180
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE,NOT_PAUSABLE,IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x1
        WAIT_HINT          : 0xbb8
        PID                : 11228
        FLAGS              :
```

Comment: possibly a security issue (different user privileges when run in ant vs. when run from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may or may not help you, but I had problems with the `<exec>` task with ant on a windows machine as well, in combination with the `<arg line=..>` statement. Ant just refused to treat the line of parameters as separate entities with spaces between them and I got weird errors like "unrecognised parameter" when it should have been a valid one.

My problems disappeared after I exchanged the one `<arg line=>` with one `<arg value=...>` for every parameter instead.
I also had to do it like Raghuram specified, and wrap everything in a shell environment as well.

Might be worth a try.

Comment: This worked for me.  The trick was to put EVERY parameter in a seperate <arg value="" />.  My block looks like: <exec executable="sc.exe">
   <arg value="\\server" />
   <arg value="stop" />
   <arg value="servcice name" />
  </exec>

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this needs a shell environment.  How about trying `cmd /c sc ...`

```
<exec executable="cmd.exe" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="/c sc \\@{server} @{operation} @{service}"/>
</exec>
```